# How to reverse the String.Format("{0:C}"..)

Tags: c#

We use following code to convert a decimal to a string,

```
td_1.InnerText = String.Format("{0:C}", price)
```

so the result could be any of following cases:

```
4.83 -> $4.83
0 -> $0.00
-30.24 -> ($30.24)
```

my question is if there any way I can reverse the string back to a signed decimal? For example:

```
$4.83 ->4.83
($30.24) -> -30.24
```

I tried decimal.tryparse, doesn't seem work. Here is my code

```
decimal number;
if (Decimal.TryParse(price, out number) && number <0)
               ...
```

Comment: Can yuo show us the code for what you tried so we can help you see where the problem is? Also, what happened when you used `TryParse`; what sort of exception did it throw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried adding NumberStyles, like:

```
decimal.Parse(currencyValue, NumberStyles.Currency);
```